# Greasemonkey - Change YouTube meta tag

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have the following script using GreaseMonkey:

```
// @name     YouTube Edit
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// @match    https://www.youtube.com/*
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
    document.querySelector("meta[name='theme-color']")
        .setAttribute("content", '#4c4c4c');
})();
```

I am trying to change the content of the `meta tag` with `name` of `theme-color` using a `querySelector`. However, when I inspect the page source of YouTube the content of this particular `meta tag` does not change.

The default `theme-color` for YouTube is `#ff0000`

Comment: Page source won't change. This is the original page source. You will see the change in devtools inspector, which displays the current live DOM.

Comment: If you are viewing the actual source of the HTML then you will still see the red value as the default. If you are viewing the live DOM in the developer window (F12) then the content will be altered, after your script runs.

Comment: Oh, okay. Yes, the dev tools show the updated theme-color. Thanks.